# PKCS#11 interop convert in .net core error in RHEL

Tags: .net-core, rhel, pkcs#11, pkcs11interop

I am using PKCS#11 interop version 1.3. Converted this version in .netcore 3.1.
While with .netcore application it is working fine in windows environment but giving error in RHEL

> Method C_FindObjectsInit returned CKR_TEMPLATE_INCONSISTENT

I know that latest version of interop support `.netstandard2.0`. So it would be easy to create application in .netcore 3.1. But I am having few restriction so have to use only PKCS#11 interop 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Pkcs11Interop 1.3 did not work correctly on 64-bit Linux.
Your best bet is to update it to the newest version available.